# programmatically merge .reg file into win32 registry

Tags: unit-testing, registry

What's the best way to programmatically merge a .reg file into the registry? This is for unit testing; the .reg file is a test artifact which will be added then removed at the start and end of testing.

Or, if there's a better way to unit test against the registry...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to remove registry keys using a .reg file, although I'm not sure how well it's documented.  Here's how:

```
REGEDIT4

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<otherpath>]
```

The `-` in front of the key name tells `Regedit` that you want to remove the key.

To run this silently, type:

```
regedit /s "myfile.reg"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're shelling out, I'd use the reg command (details below). If you can tell us what language you're working with, we could provide language specific code.

C:>reg /?

REG Operation [Parameter List]

Operation  [ QUERY   | ADD    | DELETE  | COPY    |
               SAVE    | LOAD   | UNLOAD  | RESTORE |
               COMPARE | EXPORT | IMPORT  | FLAGS ]

Return Code: (Except for REG COMPARE)

0 - Successful
  1 - Failed

For help on a specific operation type:

REG ADD /?
  REG DELETE /?
[snipped]

Answer (score 2):

I looked into it by checking out my file associations.

It seems that a .reg file is just called as the first parameter to the `regedit.exe` executable on Windows.

So you can just say `regedit.exe "mytest.reg"`. What I'm not sure of is how to get rid of the dialog box that pops up that asks for your confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Win32 API function ShellExecute() or ShellExecuteEx(). If the comment is 'open' it should merge the .reg file. I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "If the comment is 'open'" Johnny Mathis?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most frustrating things about writing unit tests is dealing with dependencies.  One of the greatest things about Test-Driven Development is that it produces code that is decoupled from its dependencies.  Cool, huh?

When I find myself asking questions like this one, I look for ways to decouple the code I'm writing from the dependency.  Separate out the reading of the registry from the complexity that you'd like to test.