# import .reg files using win32 or other libraries

Tags: c++, c, winapi, registry

My question is a bit related to this one but it's not what I was aiming for:

[programmatically merge .reg file into win32 registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070/programmatically-merge-reg-file-into-win32-registry)

What I want to do is to create a program that can import a .reg file using win32 or some other library. I tried looking around but failed at that part. Something like a **regedit.exe /s** function. Is it possible to do this without using regedit.exe or reg.exe in anyway?

So.. no system("myfile.reg") or like ShellExecute() using reg.exe or regedit.exe

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some explanation as to why you want to do this might give some direction for answers.

Comment: And why do you dislike regedit?

Comment: I don't know what Charles is doing, but _I_ don't like regedit because it CAN'T import everything it exports.  I have a 1MB reg file that I exported, but it won't import -- some sub-keys are empty.  It appears there is some sort of internal size limitation.  Seen this at client sites too...

Comment: Another use case for this is writing just to HKCU, which shouldn't require elevated privileges, which regasm and regedit do

Answer (score 1):

Since *regedit.exe* created the reg file in the first place, I'm not really sure why you wouldn't also want it to do the import.

One other option would be to parse the reg file and then convert the parsed information into direct calls to the *RegCreateKey*, *RegSetValue* Win32 API functions, but I suspect that would be a fair amount of coding effort.