# Open an Exported Registry in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

From different machines, I have exported different branches of the registry. (The whole registry was too large to take in its entirety.)

I have saved these registries on .reg files on my own machine, and so far have only examined them as plaintext. I don't want to open them with Regedit because I don't want the keys to merge with my machine's registry.

In my C# application, in an attempt to determine if a piece of software is installed, I have been examining my machine's existing registry.

```
string REGISTRY_KEY = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
string REGISTRY_NAME = "Name of Software";
bool is64bit = true;
RegistryView registryView = is64Bit ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
RegistryKey registryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView).OpenSubKey(REGISTRY_KEY);
if (registryKey != null)
{
    using (registryKey)
    {
        foreach (string subkeyName in registryKey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subkey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(subkeyName))
            {
                string displayName = (string)subkey.GetValue("DisplayName");
                if (displayName != null && displayName.Contains(REGISTRY_NAME))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Found the program" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This searches within the 64-bit view of my machine's HKLM.

However, now I want to run this same code, but instead of using my machine's registry file, I want to use one of the exported .reg files I have.
The branch I exported from is the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` branch.

How do I use the RegistryKey tools with C# to open a registry file saved on my machine (but is not the actual registry for my own machine)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but AFAIK there's no way you can do that with built-in .NET registry functions; you will have to build your own text parser or use one that's already been  made to get the keys inside your file.

See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02a19067-16ea-4475-8267-1122a17ca35f/how-to-read-a-regfile-reg?forum=vbgeneral) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242023/import-reg-files-using-win32-or-other-libraries) saying the same thing; [this project](https://github.com/EricZimmerman/Registry) is a registry parser with about 40 stars on GitHub.

Comment: Btw it's been almost 20 days since you asked this question; did you come up with something else?

Comment: I have unfortunately not found a solution.