# Using C++ to Merge .reg files

Tags: c++, c, registry, command-prompt

Hey, I am simply trying to merge a .reg file into my registry using a very basic c++ program.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string file = "regedit.exe  new.reg";
    const char* ctv = file.c_str(); 

    system(ctv);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried using these system commands:

```
ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", "new.reg", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
system("reg import new.reg");
system("regedit/s new.reg");
system("new.reg");
```

but they work no better.
The very interesting thing is that if I go to Start, Run, and type in "regedit.exe new.reg"
The registry WILL update; just not when I run the .exe program. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300524/using-c-to-import-registry-files

Comment: This requires elevated permissions in any modern version of Windows.  Add the required manifest to your program.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [programmatically merge .reg file into win32 registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070/programmatically-merge-reg-file-into-win32-registry) and additionally [import .reg files using win32 or other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242023/import-reg-files-using-win32-or-other-libraries).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889%28VS.85%29.aspx as well which might help.

> **RegLoadKey Function**
>
> Creates a subkey under HKEY_USERS or
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and loads the data
>   from the specified registry hive into
>   that subkey.
>
> Applications that back up or restore
>   system state including system files
>   and registry hives should use the
>   Volume Shadow Copy Service instead of
>   the registry functions.

Just FYI, here is the piece of code from the linked open-source project which handles imports:

```
void CMainFrame::ImportRegistryFiles(CString csFileName)
{
    CStdioFileEx sfRegFile;
    TRY
    {
        sfRegFile.Open(LPCTSTR(csFileName),CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeText);
    }
    CATCH( CFileException, e )
    {
        CString csError = _T("");
        csError.Format(_T("File could not be opened: %s"), e->m_cause);
        MessageBox(csError,_T("Import Error"), MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }
    END_CATCH

    CNtRegistry ntReg;
    ntReg.InitNtRegistry();

    //
    DWORD dwRegType = 0;
    int nDataStarts = 0;

    CTokenEx tok;
    UCHAR ucData[8192];

    CString csValueName = _T("");
    CString csFullKey = _T("");
    CString csData = _T("");

    BOOL bNextLine = FALSE;
    BOOL bKeyFound = FALSE;
    BOOL bHiddenKey = FALSE;

    CString csLine = _T("");
    while (sfRegFile.ReadString(csLine)) {
        //
        if (csLine.Left(3) == _T("[HK")) {
            //
            csLine.TrimLeft("[");
            csLine.TrimRight("]");

            CStringArray csaKeyPath;
            CString csFullPath = GetRegistryPath(csLine,csaKeyPath);

            if (csFullPath.Right(1) == "*") {
                // User wants to create a "Hidden" Key ...
                bHiddenKey = TRUE;
            }

            if (!ntReg.KeyExists(csFullPath)) {
                //
                csFullKey = csaKeyPath.GetAt(0);
                for (int n=1; n<csaKeyPath.GetSize(); n++) {
                    //
                    csFullKey += _T("\\");
                    csFullKey += csaKeyPath.GetAt(n);
                    if (n == (csaKeyPath.GetSize()-1) && csFullKey.Right(1) == "*") {
                        CString csTmp = csFullKey;
                        csFullKey = csTmp.Left(csTmp.GetLength()-1);
                        if (!ntReg.CreateHiddenKey(csFullKey)) {
                            //
                            sfRegFile.Close();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!ntReg.SetKey(csFullKey,TRUE,TRUE)) {
                        //
                        sfRegFile.Close();
                        return;
                    }
                    theApp.m_clsTV->TraverseTree(csFullKey);
                }
            }
            else {
                //
                if (!ntReg.SetKey(csFullPath,TRUE,TRUE)) {
                    //
                    sfRegFile.Close();
                    return;
                }
                theApp.m_clsTV->TraverseTree(csFullKey);
            }
            bKeyFound = TRUE;
            nDataStarts = 0;
            dwRegType = REG_NONE;
            csData = _T("");
        }
        else if ((csLine.Left(2) == _T("@=") || 
                 csLine.Left(1) == _T("=") || 
                 csLine.Left(1) == _T("\"")) && 
                 bKeyFound) {
            //
            memset(ucData,0,8192);
            dwRegType = BreakdownLineInfo(csLine, csValueName, nDataStarts);

#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
            csLine.Trim();      // _VC80_
#else
            csLine.TrimLeft();
            csLine.TrimRight();
#endif
            csData = csLine.Mid(nDataStarts);
            if (csLine.Right(1) == _T("\\")) {
                bNextLine = TRUE;
                csData.TrimRight(_T("\\"));
            }
            else {
                // SetValue in Registry
                bNextLine = FALSE;
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
                csData.Trim();      // _VC80_
#else
                csData.TrimLeft();
                csData.TrimRight();
#endif
                csData.TrimRight(_T("\""));

                BOOL bError = FALSE;
                switch (dwRegType) {
                    case REG_SZ:
                        bError = ntReg.WriteString(csFullKey,csValueName,csData);
                        break;

                    case REG_EXPAND_SZ:
                        //
                        {
                            CString csNewData = _T("");
                            CString csTmpData = _T("");
                            int nCtr = 0;
                            tok.Split(csData,_T(","));
                            for (int n=0; n<tok.m_csaAddIt.GetSize(); n++) {
                                int nDec = theApp.Hex2Dec(tok.m_csaAddIt.GetAt(n));
                                if (nDec != 0) {
                                    csNewData.Format(_T("%c"),nDec); 
                                    csNewData += csTmpData;
                                }
                            }
                            bError = ntReg.WriteExpandString(csFullKey,csValueName,csNewData);
                        }
                        break;

                    case REG_DWORD:
                    case REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN:
                        {
                            DWORD dwData = theApp.Hex2Dec(csData);
                            bError = ntReg.WriteDword(csFullKey,csValueName,dwData);
                        }
                        break;

                    case REG_MULTI_SZ:
                        //
                        {
                            CStringArray csaData;
                            CString csNewData = _T("");
                            CString csTmpData = _T("");
                            int nCtr = 0;
                            tok.Split(csData,_T(","));
                            for (int n=0; n<tok.m_csaAddIt.GetSize(); n++) {
                                int nDec = theApp.Hex2Dec(tok.m_csaAddIt.GetAt(n));
                                if (nDec != 0) {
                                    csNewData.Format(_T("%c"),nDec); 
                                    csNewData += csTmpData;
                                }
                                else {
                                    if ((n+1) < tok.m_csaAddIt.GetSize()) {
                                        int nDec2 = theApp.Hex2Dec(tok.m_csaAddIt.GetAt(n+1));
                                        if (nDec2 == 0 && csNewData != _T("")) {
                                            csaData.Add(csNewData);
                                            csNewData = _T("");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            bError = ntReg.WriteMultiString(csFullKey,csValueName,csaData);
                        }
                        break;

                    case REG_BINARY:
                    case REG_LINK:
                    case REG_RESOURCE_LIST:
                    case REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR:
                    case REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST:
                    case REG_QWORD:
                        //
                        {
                            int nCtr = 0;
                            tok.Split(csData,_T(","));
                            for (int n=0; n<tok.m_csaAddIt.GetSize(); n++) {
                                int nDec = theApp.Hex2Dec(tok.m_csaAddIt.GetAt(n));
                                ucData[nCtr++] = nDec;
                            }
                            UINT uiLength = (UINT)nCtr+1;
                            bError = ntReg.WriteValue(csFullKey, csValueName, ucData, (ULONG)uiLength, dwRegType);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //
            memset(ucData,0,8192);
            if (bNextLine) {
                //
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
                csLine.Trim();      // _VC80_
#else
                csLine.TrimLeft();
                csLine.TrimRight();
#endif
                if (csLine.Right(1) != _T("\\")) {
                    //
                    bNextLine = FALSE;
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
                    csData.Trim();      // _VC80_
#else
                    csData.TrimLeft();
                    csData.TrimRight();
#endif
                    csData.TrimRight(_T("\""));

                    BOOL bError = FALSE;
                    csData += csLine;

                    // SetValue in Registry
                    switch (dwRegType) {
                        case REG_SZ:
                            bError = ntReg.WriteString(csFullKey,csValueName,csData);
                            break;

                        case REG_EXPAND_SZ:
                            //
                            {
                                CString csNewData = _T("");
                                CString csTmpData = _T("");
                                int nCtr = 0;
                                tok.Split(csData,_T(","));
                                for (int n=0; n<tok.m_csaAddIt.GetSize(); n++) {
                                    int nDec = theApp.Hex2Dec(tok.m_csaAddIt.GetAt(n));
                                    if (nDec != 0) {
                                        csTmpData.Format(_T("%c"),nDec); 
                                        csNewData += csTmpData;
                                    }
                                }
                                bError = ntReg.WriteExpandString(csFullKey,csValueName,csNewData);
                            }
                            break;

                        case REG_DWORD:
                        case REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN:
                            {
                                DWORD dwData = theApp.Hex2Dec(csData);
                                bError = ntReg.WriteDword(csFullKey,csValueName,dwData);
                            }
                            break;

                        case REG_MULTI_SZ:
                            //
                            {
                                CStringArray csaData;
                                CString csNewData = _T("");
                                CString csTmpData = _T("");
                                int nCtr = 0;
                                tok.Split(csData,_T(","));
                                for (int n=0; n<tok.m_csaAddIt.GetSize(); n++) {
                                    int nDec = theApp.Hex2Dec(tok.m_csaAddIt.GetAt(n));
                                    if (nDec != 0) {
                                        csTmpData.Format(_T("%c"),nDec); 
                                        csNewData += csTmpData;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if ((n+1) < tok.m_csaAddIt.GetSize()) {
                                            int nDec2 = theApp.Hex2Dec(tok.m_csaAddIt.GetAt(n+1));
                                            if (nDec2 == 0 && csNewData != _T("")) {
                                                csaData.Add(csNewData);
                                                csNewData = _T("");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                bError = ntReg.WriteMultiString(csFullKey,csValueName,csaData);
                            }
                            break;

                        case REG_BINARY:
                        case REG_LINK:
                        case REG_RESOURCE_LIST:
                        case REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR:
                        case REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST:
                        case REG_QWORD:
                            //
                            {
                                int nCtr = 0;
                                tok.Split(csData,_T(","));
                                for (int n=0; n<tok.m_csaAddIt.GetSize(); n++) {
                                    int nDec = theApp.Hex2Dec(tok.m_csaAddIt.GetAt(n));
                                    ucData[nCtr++] = nDec;
                                }
                                UINT uiLength = (UINT)nCtr+1;
                                bError = ntReg.WriteValue(csFullKey, csValueName, ucData, (ULONG)uiLength, dwRegType);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    csData += csLine;
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
                    csLine.Trim();      // _VC80_
#else
                    csLine.TrimLeft();
                    csLine.TrimRight();
#endif
                    csData.TrimRight(_T("\\"));
                }
            }
            else {
                bKeyFound = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, but neither of them really gave much help;
the first details API functions, mentioning 'regedit.exe "mytest.reg"', which I've already tested, and the second only really provided suggestions for googling.. which i've done.

Comment: Did you have a look at the MSDNAA API link? It'd be nice if they offered a concrete example on there too. What I could suggest is finding some open-source reg editor and nicking the code from that.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/NtRegEdit.aspx

Comment: I found a much simpler way to do it through VB. Thanks for your assistance, though.